# How to print X Axis co-ordinate values to console in a d3 react line chart

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, svg

I am new to d3 with react  and looking if there is a way to print the x Axis tick translate value to console

[image]

I need these points for some other functionality and could like there is a way to capture these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scale.ticks()`, this is how the axis generates the ticks, not through functionality specific to the axis, but the scale:

```
// Without tickArguments (same as default behavior):
var ticks = x.ticks(count); // count is optional, defaults to 10, number not always achieved in order to get clean round tick values.

// If tickArguments are specified:
var ticks = x.ticks(...axis.tickArguments())
```

Once you get the tick values(unscaled), you can scale them to get the scaled/translated values, perhaps something like:

```js
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0,100])
  .range([0,500]);
  
var axis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(x)
  .tickArguments([20, "s"]);
  
// Without tickArguments:
var ticks = x.ticks();
var xValues = ticks.map(function(t) {
  return x(t);
})
console.log(xValues);

// With tickArguments:
var ticks = x.ticks(...axis.tickArguments())
var xValues = ticks.map(function(t) {
  return x(t);
})
console.log(xValues);


// With a specific count and no tick arguments:
var ticks = x.ticks(2)
var xValues = ticks.map(function(t) {
  return x(t);
})
console.log(xValues);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```